# Import Attachments to Roundcube (by external button)

Tags: roundcube

As part of a production, I've created an HTML page to upload files. My page has a button that lets me import the file, and a "Send" button that lets me send the file.

For the time being, I've made sure that when I press "Send", a new window appears for writing a new e-mail on Roundcube.

So I wanted to know if there was a plugin or function that would allow me to make sure that as soon as I press "Send" (after importing the file to be sent), my new window for writing appears with the file already attached.

I tried using the Roundcube API, but couldn't figure out how to use it, even after reading the documentation.

For the moment my code is pretty simplistic (it's just forms) so I don't see the point of posting it

(I've also already posted a topic on the roundcube forum but I've had no response so that's why i'm asking here)

Comment: After some research i was able to find a plugin that suit my case well it it using the message_compose() function but when i'm attaching a file the file is empty ( always at 0 kO)